# How to multiplex on senders?

Tags: rust

I have a bunch of SyncSenders. I want to get a "ready to send" set.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
for c in data {
  loop {
    for tx in sync_senders {
      if let Ok(_) = tx.try_send(c) {    
        do something;
        ...
      }
    }
    until some sends are success, break
  }
}
```

Is there a way to multiplex on SyncSenders, so I can get a ready set of them?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it, I would probably just set up another (async) channel and make the worker threads send their sender back as soon as they are idle…

```
 while let Ok(sender) = sync_senders.recv() {
    ...
 }
```

But why do you want to do that? Maybe a [multiple-consumer channel](http://mahkoh.github.io/comm/doc/comm/index.html) fits better for your purpose?